# Cache busting in Django 1.8?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.8 and I want to add a parameter to my static files to cache bust.

This is what I'm doing right now, setting a manual parameter:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/openprescribing.css' %}?q=0.1.1" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I feel there must be a better way to update the parameter.

I guess it would be a bit neater to have a setting passed through the template (and that would save having to update it in multiple places).

But what would be really nice is if Django could update it automatically for me.

The notes on [django-cachebuster](https://github.com/jaddison/django-cachebuster) suggest that it's now possible to do this automatically in [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/), but I can't find anything in the staticfiles docs about it.

Anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Caching? If so then there are better approaches than what you wish to accomplish. If you're using Django 1.8, running with Nginx, then I suggest you let Nginx do the caching for you, whiles Django does what it does best.

Comment: @Rexford I'm using Nginx, yes, with CloudFlare. I want to cache bust (ie have users automatically see the new file when I upload a new file). Are you suggesting Nginx will automatically cache bust for me? If so, can you provide details?

Comment: See my answer below, as long as that's what you wish to accomplish, i.e, see any newly re-uploaded content immediately, nginx gives you such feature for free! No django, no cache-busters may be needed.

Comment: Note that caching via Nginx offers absolutely not guarantee that the browsers won't also cache previously sent files based on name. Server-based caching is unreliable at best and should not be your only approach.

Answer (score 17):

Yes this can be done automatically with `contrib.staticfiles`. There are two additional provided storage classes which will rename files using a hash. These
are documented here: [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) and [CachedStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cachedstaticfilesstorage)

From the docs:

> A subclass of the StaticFilesStorage storage backend which stores the file names it handles by appending the MD5 hash of the file’s content to the filename. For example, the file css/styles.css would also be saved as css/styles.55e7cbb9ba48.css.
>
> The purpose of this storage is to keep serving the old files in case some pages still refer to those files, e.g. because they are cached by you or a 3rd party proxy server. Additionally, it’s very helpful if you want to apply far future Expires headers to the deployed files to speed up the load time for subsequent page visits.

The main difference is

> CachedStaticFilesStorage is a similar class like the ManifestStaticFilesStorage class but uses Django’s caching framework for storing the hashed names of processed files instead of a static manifest file called staticfiles.json. This is mostly useful for situations in which you don’t have access to the file system.

To enable them you need to change your `STATICFILES_STORAGE` setting is set to `'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'` or `'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'`. The file names are only changed when `DEBUG=False` as it would be in production.

Comment: What if the file is served from a CDN?

Comment: I did not notice this note, but it's important: "The file names are only changed when DEBUG=False as it would be in production." In dev, I have to shift-refresh to get new assets.

Comment: For information, `'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'` is now deprecated (since release 3.x if I'm not wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Caching, but I think letting nginx handle caching might be better than using Django. Django has a lot to handle, so you can let the lightweight static server do that nasty job.

I do not use cloudflare, but I use this line to cache my statics, however, immediately the file changes, Nginx propagates the most recent file (thats the same file):

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 30d;
    }
```

which is a snippet [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/seanmavley/19bbdf2b796d3c19b7f7) I'm currently using that conf in *production*, so I know it works.

One thing I'll point out is, make sure MemCached isn't working and connected to your django as a Caching Backend. I say this, because I have spent many hours in time past hitting my head against the wall, simply because MemCached was caching my page with every content in it for up to 10 minutes.

with this nginx location conf, Whenever I change my .css, or upload a new file (static), the new file immediately takes over, as long as I've `python manage.py collectstatic`'ed them into the appropriate directory

I stand to be corrected though, if that's not actually the part doing the trick.

**Proof that above works with Cache-busting (as you call it)**

- I went into server
- Deleted my static folder (nginx still running) `sudo rm -rf static/`
- Accessed my site
- No static loaded
- Went back, and `python manage.py collectstatic`
- Accessed my site again. Statics loaded
- No browser hard refresh was used. No nginx reload|restart whatever was used.

Nginx is smart enough to cache your statics, but reload the static when the file is new and serve it.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the browser has now cached that file for 30d. Even though nginx knows to serve new ones the browser won't make the request. The browser will only make a new request if the url has changed which is what the hash in the filename achieves.

Comment: Also I need to cache bust things I'm serving from a CDN sometimes, not served by my local server.  I think both work, but sometimes you really need to cache bust in Django templates.

Answer (score -2):

If you use a CDN, cache busting becomes more complex. If you just want to bust the cache for a specific image, just create a simple tag that does the trick....

```
import time
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def cache_bust():
  return int(time.time())
```

Then in your template just do something like this...

```
{% load cache_app %}
<img src="/captcha/?cache_bust={% cache_bust %}" class="captcha"/>
```

And you have cache busting the simple way.

Comment: As a community, if this is not a good answer, can we get a comment as to why? Thanks! I'm here to learn as much as share.

Comment: This is not a good solution, you would want cache busting only when an image changes. This solution would fetch a new image from your server every single time the page loads.

Comment: How would you implement cache busting that detects if the image changed in a CDN?